# How can I acknowledge only a single message in JMS from a consumer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I have a consumer that checks a Queue for messages and then tries to do some processing based on the message. If something goes wrong, it should leave the message in the queue, otherwise it should acknowledge receipt and remove it form the Queue.

Reading the docs, it appears that using `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` and calling `acknowledge` on a single message will acknowledge *all* messages that were received during that session.

> static final int CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
>
> With this acknowledgment mode, the client acknowledges a consumed message by calling the message's acknowledge method. Acknowledging a consumed message acknowledges all messages that the session has consumed.

That would mean I'd need to make a separate session for *every* message I'm consuming. That seems very inefficient. Is there some better way to handle this? (Perhaps a way to put a message back in the queue)

Would it simply be better to make a new message "clone" and put that in the queue for ones that I want to "fail" and return to the queue?

```
/** All of this is in a loop checking for messages in one session **/

//It's ok
if ( Handler.messageOK( pushMessage ) )
{
    //Remove from queue
    message.acknowledge();
}

//I know this isn't right but how put it back?
else
{
    //Recover the message for retry
    jmsSession.recover();
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime environment of the consumer? You're not using MDBs?

Comment: @SteveC Tomcat 8, ActiveMQ, Weld CDI. No MDB.

Comment: Pity that. Message processing in MDBs is transactional. The container automatically requeues messages if the transaction is marked for rollback (such as by throwing a RuntimeException). You will find life much easier using a full Java EE stack.

Comment: @SteveC I agree and tried too argue for that but I'm stuck with tomcat. btw, i think I can achieve what i want if i add `connection.start()` anger the call to recover.